# Doctrine - Acessar a variável $entityManager criada no bootstrap.php de dentro de uma Classe

Tags: php, mvc, arquitetura-de-software, doctrine, doctrine-2

estou estudando Doctrine e estou adaptando um projeto que já tinha desenvolvido em MVC para trabalhar com o Doctrine. Estou tendo uma certa dúvida em como proceder em relação à variável **$entityManager** que crio no **bootstrap.php** para ser acessada dentro de uma classe Controller, ou seja ele no **bootstrap.php** é instanciado, porém dentro do Controller eu não consigo ter acesso a ele. Olhando o log do apache dá o seguinte erro:

```
Fatal error:  Call to a member function getRepository() on a non-object in /var/www/html/projetoTeste/src/Projeto/Core/Controller/GruposController.php on line 12
```

Eu estou pensando em criar uma classe para o bootstrap só para conseguir herdar, de alguma forma, nos meus Controllers. Mas tô em dúvida se é necessário mesmo.

Bem a estrutura do projeto é assim: tenho o **index.php** que faz require do **bootstrap.php**, nele rodo o método `Projeto\FrontController::run();` que controla o roteamento, ou seja, quais classes e views serão chamadas. Deixando claro então, o **bootstrap.php** sempre será rodado antes de qualquer classe ser instanciada.

Segue os códigos:
http://pastebin.com/zUaKnECH

---

**Edit [17/07/2014]**

Pessoal, não consegui de jeito nenhum por pra funcionar usando global. Para colocar para funcionar instanciei numa classe DAO genérica e herdei dela. Consegui pôr pra funcionar, porém não consigo enxergar seus métodos, tipo ao utilizar o método **`getRepository()`**, inicio **`$entityManager->`** só que não aparece a lista dos métodos herdados e instanciados nesta variável do tipo Objeto.

Mas se eu completar a chamada do método na mão mesmo, ficando assim:

```
$entityManager->getRepository($this->entidade);
return $entityRepository->findAll();
```

Ele consegue retornar os dados do Banco de Dados. Ou seja, apenas não terei disponível a lista de métodos disponível pelo objeto, ficando meio que perdido sem saber o que utilizar em determinadas situações já que ainda estou aprendendo a usar o FW, me obrigando a toda hora pesquisar na internet em caso destas dúvidas.

Será que tem alguma forma de forçar minha IDE apresentar esta lista? Estou usando [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/).

Answer (score 3):

Além de colocar sua classe bootstrap no seu controller através do `requre/require_once`, você também necessita colocar o `$entityManager` com a tag `global` na sua function, por exemplo:

```
public function minhafuncao() {
    global $entityManager;
    // resto do método
}
```

Comment: Acho que sua resposta é suficiente para essa pergunta, mas cuide com os erros ortográficos...

Comment: Bacana Eduardo! Estava precisando de algo muito parecido (ps: não qual erro?)

Comment: LeoFelipe, legal que te ajudou. Se resolveu seu problema, por favor, marque a resposta como resolvida.

Comment: Desculpem a demora em responder... Bem, +EduardoFernandes, como expliquei não necessito fazer require no meu Controller, pois já faço o require no meu index.php e controlo minhas rotas com classe de roteamento e .htaccess... no bootstrap.php, que não é uma classe, defini como global o $entityManagar, mas não dentro de um método, como demonstro no meu código apresentado, há diferença? Por isto não marquei como resolvido.

Comment: Caro @LeoFelipe, veja a referência a seguir que fala sobre coo tratar variáveis globais em functions. Note que há a necessidade da declaração da variável como global. http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Pessoal, consegui pôr para funcionar de uma forma paleativa. Fiz a atualização lá no Post.